# my location point appears out of the street google maps eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I developed an application for Android in Eclipse with Google maps. The problem is that the blue dot indicating my current location appears always parallel to the road where I am driving, on roads outside cities. But if you are within the city the point already on top of the road.

I'm using this to get my location on the start of the app:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
```

then I add the blue dot to the map:

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

and then I start listening for location changes:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, 1, this);
```

My location change function:

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {

            Lat1 = location.getLatitude();
            Long1 = location.getLongitude();

            if (Lat1 != Lat || Long1 != Long) {
                Lat = location.getLatitude();
                Long = location.getLongitude();
                if (startNav == true) {
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 17));
                    b = new LatLng(Lat, Long);
                    if (a != null) {
                        String urlTopass = makeURL(b.latitude, b.longitude, a.latitude, a.longitude);
                        new connectAsyncTask(urlTopass).execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is why does the blue dot appear parallel to the street instead of on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the  [FusedLocationProviderAPI](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi). It is recommended over using the older open source Location APIs, especially since you're already using a Google Map so you are already using Google Play Services.

Simply set up a Location Listener, and update your current location Marker in each onLocationChanged() callback. If you only want one location update, just un-register for callbacks after the first callback returns.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    if (map == null) {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap retMap) {
    map = retMap;
    setUpMap();
}

public void setUpMap(){
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;

    //remove previous current location Marker
    if (marker != null){
        marker.remove();
    }

    double dLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
    double dLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
    marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude))
            .title("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude), 8));

}
}
```